# date range linq query efficiency

Tags: linq, date, foreach, range

I've been tasked with designing a page to generate an inventory/sales report for a sql server inventory database consisting of the following: beginning stock, end of day stock, delivered items, sold items for a given day or range of days.

What I ended up doing is using a for loop to go through the range of days that stats are needed for and keeping a running tally of the stats for each day that is returned from my query.

The parts table has a field named quantity that keeps track of the current stock for each item in the inventory. The deliveries table contains records of when items are delivered and the sales table contains records of when sales are made.

Because of certain restrictions, I've been only able to figure out the ending stock for a certain day for a given item by taking the current stock quantity and subtracting from it the quantity delivered and adding to that number the quantity sold for that day. I then do this x number of times for each day in the range of dates needed while keeping a running tally for the totals.

To get the stats for a single day, the following query performs adequately, but when stats are needed for a range of days, the performance deteriorates quite badly. As I said I'm not very proficient with linq and would really appreciate any help to improve the following query's performance.

edit: code was broken

Answer (score 2):

The best way to improve performance is to move all this logic to the database, by creating a view, for example. It's very hard to be faster than a DB when it comes to joining and groping data.

Comment: I was thinking I might have to go this route, but would love to know if there's a way to optimize my current solution.

Comment: @Steve In short, there isn't.  You are trying to use the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 2):

For a complex query of this kind, LINQ is simply not the right tool for the job.  A "Stats" view would give you something easy to query for what you need to get individual statistics, then the aggregate should be easy to get from there